# How to match 2 files in Linux one file with 1 column and the second file with 2 columns

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have 2 files.

file 1:

```
123456789
789465123
456789132
```

file 2:

```
r6rg6r6,123456789
dfg4665,789465123
dthegfd,456789132
```

I need to match the id's and print into a file the id's

```
r6rg6r6
dfg4665
dthegfd
```

I tried with `awk`, `cmp`, `comm`, `diff` and nothing

this is the commands that im trying to run in the command line

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1]; next}($2 in a){print $1}' file1 file2 > test.csv
```

Comment: - diff file1 file2 > test.csv
- awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $1}' file1 file2 > test.csv
- comm -12 file1 file2 > text.csv

Comment: @E.M This is a scray unreadable command line. Can you [edit] your question and feed in this information there?

Comment: Are there really headers in both files? And how are the columns delimited? TABs?

Comment: there is no headers in the files i wrote that for the example

Comment: Now that you've added the script you're executing to your question it's obvious that you just forgot to tell awk what the Field Separator is you're using in your input. Just change `awk '...'` to `awk -F, '...'` and your script will work. It's important when asking questions to provide a [mcve] which includes concise, testable sample input and expected output plus your attempt at solving the problem yourself. Had you done that right away you'd have had your answer 2 hours ago.

Comment: still nothing awk -F '(NR==FNR){a[$1]; next}($2 in a){print $1}' file1 file2  > test.csv

Comment: ooh the input changed ;-)

Comment: @E.M you forgot the `,` it is `-F,` and not `-F`

Comment: thank you guys for your help

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `grep`, it is mighty powerful

```
grep -F <file1> <file2> | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

or just `awk`:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1]; next}($2 in a){print $1}' <file1> <file2>
```

However, since you already tried this solution, it might be a problem with CRLF terminations due to a dos/windows copy. While you can resolve this with `dos2unix`, you can also use the following `awk` line (GNU awk only):

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' '(NR==FNR){a[$1]; next}($2 in a){print $1}' <file1> <file2>
```

Comment: im tring to do 
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1]; next}($2 in a){print $1}' <file1> <file2> > test.csv and i get an empty file

Comment: @E.M What you are probably suffering from is the dos carriage return `\r`. In "dos"-files. line termination is done with `\r\n` while in unix lines it is `\n` only. Since `awk` uses `\n` as a record separator, your indices or `$2` fields have an extra `\r`. This is why a match will always fail. You can check this with the command `file <filex>` and you can convert with `dos2unix`.

Comment: but there is no extra \r

Comment: @E.M Are you indicating that `file <filename1>` and `file <filename2>` both return `ASCII text` and not `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: one returning  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators and the other ASCII text

Comment: @E.M. That is your problem. You have the `\r\n` line terminations. Just run `dos2unix <file>` on that file and it will solve the problem.

Comment: can you tell me if there is another way to make dos2unix? because i get  dos2unix: command not found

Comment: @E.M I have added an alternative approach to my answer. (btw are you running on a linux box or a dos-box?)

Comment: id did now i get both files ASCII text and still in the output get an empty file

Comment: This is now getting fairly impossible. Can you [edit] your question and show your attempts what you have done (including all output of the `file` command`)

Comment: in command line i write the awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1]; next}($2 in a){print $1}' file1 file2 > test.csv and still emapty. my question still the same.

Comment: OP significantly changed the format of input files. This command works with comma as a delimiter: `awk -F, '...`.